# iOS 9 ATS Whitelisting

Tags: ios, facebook, ios9

This may sound like a stupid question but I've been having some trouble understanding ATS and Whitelisting.

I use the Facebook SDK so I followed what the documentation said and made the appropriate changes on my .plist to Whitelist Facebook servers.

In my app, I make API calls to my server and I was wondering how I should go about Whitelisting that? Also, in one of the WWDC talks on ATS, they spoke about URLSchemes. If someone could explain or point me in the right direction where I can get an understanding of why it needs to be implemented and how it should be done, that would be great!

Again sorry if this sounds like a stupid question - I've tried reading articles but haven't really been able to understand it.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Actually what you want to know? How to do Facebook Whitelisting?

Comment: I have done the Facebook Whitelisting but I just wanted to know what the process would be to Whitelist other servers. How to decide on what needs to be Whitelisted and what does not. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. Then wait for the good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

Official technote :
[Apple Developer Technote for ATS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)

Console log, User Experience and Solution : [click here](https://ioscuriosity.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/app-transport-security-in-ios-9/)

Answer (score 0):

If enabled, ATS will block every HTTP request made by your App or third party libraries. 
Apple will require specific justification whether you're disabling it or putting exceptions in the NSExceptionDomains dictionary.
You're allowed to do it when you have to connect to a server not managed by you or using a device that cannot support secure connections or be requesting media content already DRM-protected.

Your .plist will look to something like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Don't forget to put the domain without the: `http://`